# EF Core: Get db records where property exists in sub list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I am trying to pass in a list of Animals and I want to get just those animals from the database. Not sure how to do an `exists` in syntax like this in EF Core

```cs
// animals is type List<Animal>()

// need something like this:
var listFromDb = _dbContext.Animals.Where(a => a.Id in animals.Select(a => a.Id));

//also tried:
_db.Animals.Where(a => animals.Contains(a.Id));
```

Comment: Your question is so unclear. please add some detail

Comment: sorry, thought it was enough. dbContext is obviously a dbcontext, animals is a dbset on that context, and there is an id prop on animals that i want to isolate the data with. any other props on animals are moot. I also had an answer for this before any responses that got downvoted for some reason even though it works as I'd like so that's interesting...

Comment: I didn't know the answer when I posted it... I was able to figure it out on my own and posted a follow up in case someone else has the same issue. Are you suggesting I leave it empty and don't respond in the future if I do figure out an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it:

```cs
            var query = _db.Animals
                .Where(a => animals.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(a.Id));
```